# any template-wise, generic way to copy similar data structure in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have a series of several similar structures, e.g.,

```
map<key1, attr1>; map<key2, attr2>; ...,
```

meanwhile, in correspondence, a series of array,

```
// JUST TO SHOW THE IDEA, NOT SYNTAX CORRECT
class {key_1; attr_1;} array [#]; class {key_2; attr_2;} array [#]; ...,
```

and keyX and key_X share the similar structure, as well as attr, e.g.

```
struct key1 {int k1;}; class key_1 {int k_1;};
struct key2 {int k1; int k2;}; class key_2 {int k_1; int k_2;};
   ...
struct attr1 {int a1; int a2;}; class attr_1 {int a_1; int a_2;};
```

I need to write a function, like overloading the assignment operator, to convert the data from map_series to the other, and vice versa.

So instead of doing it **map by map**, **key by key**, and **int by int**, is there some template-wise way to do it, so the code would be generic,or save more lines of code? What could be the smart way to do this?

**EDIT 1:**

Unfortunately, one constraint due to our legacy system, the type convertion between struct, e.g. key1, key_1, does not work as C++ primitives, so a conversion function also have to be provided.

**EDIT 2:**

inspired by J.N. answer, is it possible to have something like:

```
template <class KeyMap, class ValueMap, class KeyArr, class ValueArr> void convert (map<KeyMap, ValueMap>, class {KeyArr, ValueArr} array[]){};
```

how to generlize the conversion for key and attr? like

```
template <class KeyMap, class KeyArr> void convert_key(KeyMap, KeyArr){}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so let's suppose we have this:

```
map<KeyTypeM, ValueTypeM> m1;
struct Type1 {
    KeyTypeS Key;
    ValueTypeS Value;
};
```

Let's define the conversion function first:

```
Type1 ConvType1(const KeyTypeM& key, const ValueTypeM& value)
{
    Type1 result;
    result.Key = f(key); // user dependent
    result.Value = f(value); // user dependent

    return result;
}
```

Then, in C++, you can't return arrays. Actually you usually don't work with array, people usually prefer `std::vector`. (If you really need an array then you need to allocate it and return a pointer to it or wrap it in a smart pointer)
Then it is enough to browse the values in the map and push them into the vector:

```
vector<Type1> ConvertType1(map<KeyTypeM, ValueTypeM>& input)
{
    vector<Type1> result;
    for (auto& pair : input) // assumes C++11
        result.push_back( ConvType1(pair.first, pair.second) );
    return result;
}
```

*note*: if you do not have a C++11 compiler, use:

```
for (map<KeyTypeM, ValueTypeM>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    result.push_back( ConvType1(it->first, it->second) );
```

That will do the job for ONE map and one type. Now we can generalize the conversion function by using templates:

```
template <class OutType, class KeyType, class ValueType, class Converter>
vector<OutType> Convert(map<KeyType, ValueType>& input, Converter conv)
{
    vector<OutType> result;
    for (auto& pair : input)
        result.push_back( conv(pair.first, pair.second) );
    return result;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
auto v1 = Convert<Type1>(m1, &ConvertType1);
auto v2 = Convert<Type2>(m2, &ConvertType2);
...
```

You could go further by creating a list of types to convert using `boost::mpl` but that should be in another question.

**EDIT:** generalize the conversion of the types

As you mentioned, there's no generic way to convert the types, we'll have to write all the conversion functions. So the only thing we can do is make it more elegant by implementing implicit conversion operators like this:

```
struct KeyTypeM
{
     ... // normal members
     operator KeyTypeS() const
     {
         // do the conversion here
     }
};

 // suppose we have the same for ValueTypeM and ValueTypeS

 // We can now use a single convert function:

 template <class OutType, class KeyTypeM, class ValueType M>
 OutType ConvertToStruct(const KeyTypeM& key, const ValueTypeM& value)
 {
      OutType result;
      result.Key = key;      // will call the implicit conversion
      result.Value = value;
      return result;
 }
```

This simplifies our conversion function (updated to take into account the array)

```
template <class OutType, class KeyType, class ValueType>
void Convert(map<KeyType, ValueType>& input, OutType out[])
{
    // out must have been initialized to a proper size to hold all the elements.
    unsigned cursor = 0;
    for (map<KeyTypeM, ValueTypeM>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it, ++cursor)
        out[cursor] = ConvertToStruct<OutType>(it->first, it->second);
}
```

**EDIT 2:** We can use `std::pair` to generalize the array structure:

```
 template <class OutType, class KeyTypeM, class ValueType M>
 OutType ConvertToStruct(const KeyTypeM& key, const ValueTypeM& value)
 {
      OutType result;
      result.first = key;      // will call the implicit conversion
      result.second = value;
      return result;
 }

template <class OutKey, class OutValue, class KeyType, class ValueType>
void Convert(map<KeyType, ValueType>& input, std::pair<OutKey, OutValue> out[])
{
    // out must have been initialized to a proper size to hold all the elements.
    unsigned cursor = 0;
    for (map<KeyTypeM, ValueTypeM>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it, ++cursor)
        out[cursor] = ConvertToStruct<OutType>(it->first, it->second);
}

 // Use this way:

 std::pair<OutKey, OutValue> arr[m.size()];
 Convert(m, arr);
```

Comment: HI, J.N. Thanks a lot for the nice example. 1. unfortunately, we do not have C++11 compiler yet. 2. Can I put the array as input with reference parameter? If so, can it also be generalized? 3. You only generlize at the container level, is it also possible to generalize the element type convert, i.e., the "ConvType1"?

Comment: 2) I'll show you how with an edit. 3) Is there a general rule for the conversion ? For intsance the type in the map is always an integer and the type in the array always a string ? If there's no rules at all you can't generalize easily. You'd have the option to define `operator <<` and use lexical_cast, but that implies you have a way to convert all the types to and from string.

Comment: well, most of these key types are struct of int, and the attr are struct of int&bool. but no strict rule to follows.